# .net framework 4.6 is not installed. please reinstall or repair visual studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm working on a project that target .Net framework 4.5. and I installed visual studio 2017 with .Net framework 4.6 , I removed 4.6 and Installed 4.5..
is there any way to make visual studio work with 4.5 instead of 4.6?

Comment: Downgrading dependcies is the best way to get into trouble. Why do you want to go that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to uninstall the 4.6 framework.

Leave the 4.6 framework installed and the projects targeting the 4.5 framework version will run perfectly fine.